# cannot convert privateKey type pem.Block to type string

Tags: go

i want to generate ssh key, public and private and return as string, but i dont know how i can convert type *pem.Block in string.

this is my current code :

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "bufio"
)

func Keymaker() {
    reader := rand.Reader
    bitSize := 2048

    key, err := rsa.GenerateKey(reader, bitSize)
    if err != nil {
        //return nil, nil, err
    }

    publicKey := key.PublicKey

    var privateKey = &pem.Block{
        Type:  "PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key),
    }

    asn1Bytes, err := asn1.Marshal(publicKey)
    if err != nil {
        //return nil, nil, err
    }

    var pemkey = &pem.Block{
        Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
        Bytes: asn1Bytes,
    }

    var PublicKeyRow bytes.Buffer

    err = pem.Encode(bufio.NewWriter(&PublicKeyRow), pemkey)

    fmt.Println("public_key : ", PublicKeyRow)
    fmt.Println("private_key : ", privateKey )

    return
}


func main() {
    Keymaker()

}
```

and this is my current error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./dkim.go:46:38: cannot convert privateKey (type *pem.Block) to type string
```

I need in string format because i want to store the key in database, how i can convert (type *pem.Block) to type string ? and how i can convert  (type bytes.Buffer) to type string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PublicKeyRow` is already correct `io.Writer` that you want to write to. You do not need to create another by `buffio.NewWriter(&PublicKeyRow)`. So to convert `pem.Block` to string your last lines should look like this:

```
var PublicKeyRow bytes.Buffer

err = pem.Encode(&PublicKeyRow, pemkey)

fmt.Println("public_key : ", PublicKeyRow)
fmt.Println("public_key(string) : ", PublicKeyRow.String())
fmt.Println("private_key : ", privateKey )
```

**Update**
To get private key you could add another encode

```
var PublicKeyRow bytes.Buffer
var PrivateKeyRow bytes.Buffer

err = pem.Encode(&PublicKeyRow, pemkey)
err = pem.Encode(&PrivateKeyRow, privateKey)

fmt.Println("public_key: ", PublicKeyRow.String())
fmt.Println("private_key : ", PrivateKeyRow.String() )
```

Comment: thanks for help, problem is the private key output is not a string format ... look like this : https://gist.github.com/scaltro/0cc4ae1ba4eac12311ed846a019da59d

Comment: Did you changed your pem.Encode function according to my suggestion?

Comment: yes, for public key is working, private key is type *pem.Block